# xsl:variable scope in xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This question is in the context of XSL 1.0; specifically because shadowing of local variables is not allowed.

Given that XSL variables are lexically scoped, I don't understand why this example, taken from Michael Kay's book (p. 338 in 2/e and p. 509 in 4/e) works:

XML:

```
<program>
  <opera>
    <title>The Magic Flute</title>
    <composer>Mozart</composer>
    <date>1791</date>
  </opera>
  <opera>
    <title>Ernani</title>
    <composer>Verdi</composer>
    <date>1843</date>
  </opera>
  ...
  <composer name="Mozart">
    <fullname>Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart</fullname>
    <born>1756</born>
    <died>1791</died>
  </composer>
  ...
</program>
```

XSL:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="program/composer">
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="fullname"/></h2>
  <xsl:variable name="c" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="program/opera[composer=$c/@name]">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="title"/></p>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

Why wouldn't this be a case of declaring the variable c multiple times in the same lexical context?  I'm obviously missing something; most likely that xsl:for-each creates multiple virtual lexical contexts?  This starts to feel more like dynamic scoping, though.  I must not be thinking about this the right way.

Comment: "*why this example ... works:*" Actually, it doesn't.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Can you clarify what you mean by this?  How does this example not work?

Comment: **1.** You have two ways of spelling `xsl:value-of`, and neither of them is correct -- **2.** `<xsl:for-each select="program/opera[composer=$c/@name]">` selects nothing from the context of `composer`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing these typos.  Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Michael Kay always has the answers, you (or at least I) just must frequently re-read things before you/I get it.  In this case, from the explanation of the effect of :

> The effect of the **<xsl:for-each>** instruction is to instantiate the template body that it contains once for each node in the selected node-set.

So, that's the answer:  the local variable is lexically scope *inside each virtual template generated by the <xsl:for-each>*.

This still feels a little weird to me; it's not really lexical or dynamic scoping.  I figured this out just prior to posting the question, but went ahead an posted it anyway in case someone comes along with the same confusion that I had.

Comment: It's easier to think of it that way. Every variable is scoped to its parent in XSLT. It goes out of scope (ceases to exist) immediately when the parent is closed.